# Metamask "Confirm" button is disabled ONLY in mobile when calling my smart contract function

Tags: blockchain, solidity, metamask, ethers.js, wagmi

I am creating a React dApp using Rainbowkit + wagmi + ethers. In my smart contract, I have a function "deposit" that allows the user to deposit money in the smart contract. In Metamask desktop everything works as expected. That is:

1. The user first approve the amount to deposit calling the standard "approve" ERC20 function.
2. The user then deposits the amount in the smart contract using my own "deposit" function.

Both transactions work.

BUT when I try the same functionality in the Mobile Metamask app (iOS), the approve transaction works as expected BUT when the deposit confirmation dialog pops up, the confirm button is disabled.
[Confirm button is disabled and the method is unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdi25.jpg)

I have been banging my head the whole day with no result. Things that I tried:

- Use the wagmi hooks instead of ethers.
- Changing my deposit function.
- Update all my libraries to the latest versions and updated my app to accommodate the breaking changes...
- Version of ethers I tried:  5.6.9 and 6.6.2.
- Versions of wagmi 1.2.0 and 1.3.7.

Everything gives me the same result.

I am running my contracts on a Oasys devnet verse blockchain. That means that there is no transaction fees.  What really puzzles me is that the "approve" transaction works. Here is some code of how I am using the stuff:

My solidity deposit function:

```
function deposit(uint256 amount) external {
  if (!_isPlayerRegistered(msg.sender)) {
    _registerPlayer(msg.sender);
  }
  require(_isPlayerRegistered(msg.sender), MESSAGE_PLAYER_NOT_REGISTERED);

  bool success = reignToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
  require(success == true, MESSAGE_TRANSFER_FAILED);

  _addToBalance(msg.sender, amount);

  emit PlayerDeposit(msg.sender, amount, players[msg.sender].balance);
}
```

How I call it from the React app:
Ethers 6.6.2

```
await this.hackerAssContract.connect(this.signer)
        .getFunction("deposit").send(amount);
```

Ethers 5.6.9

```
await this.hackerAssContract.connect(this.userAddress).deposit(amount);
```

Wagmi hooks

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xdA7BDE2f4e05f275EcFdFC21051Dc604C7641D6A',
    abi: hackerassAbi,
    functionName: 'deposit',
    args: [depositValue]
  })
const { write } = useContractWrite(config)

<BlahBlah>
  <button
    disabled={depositValue == 0 || notEnoughBalance()}
     className={`btn btn-primary w-full text-center`}
     onClick={(e) => {
       e.preventDefault()
       write?.()
     }}
    >
    {depositLabel}
  </button>
</BlahBlah>
```

When using ethers, to get the provider/signer I am using the methods provided by Wagmi here:
https://wagmi.sh/react/ethers-adapters

I am running out of ideas. My next move is to change the blockchain I am testing on. If it works in BSC testnet I would at least know that this is just an Oasys issue (that won't solve my problem but at least I would know something :P)